# Google maps api keeps loading on firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The page where i ude google map on it is keep loading on firefox it says "waiting for maps.googleapis.com.." the map is appearing properly but some other things on site like youtube video is not loading as this maps did not finish loading

code used is

```
var is_init = false;
var map;
function map_init() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.65578083204094, 138.9385986328125);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: latlng,
        scrollwheel: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID     };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var marker;
    var latlng;

            is_init = true;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you initialize your map in the onload event.

If you're using jQuery:

```
$(window).load(map_init);
```

This fixed the problem for me.